# Erase and Partition Hard Drive in Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

If I want to erase and partition a drive on my Mac I can use Disk Utility. From there I can erase the drive and select a format (FAT32, Mac OS Extended...) as well as partition the drive. I am wondering how I can perform this same procedure in Linux using the command line. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the name of the device that's associated with your disk. Running the `dmesg` command might help you here if you don't know it. This command prints to the screen the kernel messages, and one of these messages should be the detection of your disk at boot time (or when it was connected to the running system). Let's assume it's `/dev/sdf'.

Then, you can use the command `fdisk /dev/sdf`. You may have to run this with the `sudo` command - `sudo fdisk /dev/sdf`. See [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html) for fdisk help. There are other utilities beside this to accomplish the task.

After you've partitioned the disk, you'll now have other devices available that represent the various partitions. These will have the same device name as the main device, with a number appended representing the partition number. Let's work with the first partition, `/dev/sdf1`.

To create an ext4 filesystem, run `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdf1`.

To create a DOS filesystem, run `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdf1`.

At the command line, try `man fdisk`, `man mkfs`, `man mkfs.ext4`, etc.

A Google search will also turn up a plethora of pages that describe how to do this in more detail. See [this search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=linux%20partitioning%20and%20formatting&safe=off), and [this result](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Linux/LINUX_PartitioningandFormattingSecondHardDrive_ext3.shtml) as a sample.